# Submit Spark Job to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: apache-spark, google-compute-engine

Has everyone tries deploy Spark using https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/mc/template/hadoop?

Spark installed correctly for me, I can SSH into the hadoop worker or master, spark is installed at /home/hadoop/spark-install/

I can use spark python shell to read file at cloud storage

> > > lines = sc.textFile("hello.txt")
> > >
> > > lines.count()
> > >
> > > line.first()

but I cannot sucessfully submit the python example to spark cluster, when I run

bin/spark-submit --master spark://hadoop-m-XXX:7077 examples/src/main/python/pi.py 10

I always got

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/yuanwang/programming/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/examples/src/main/python/pi.py",
>   line 38, in 
>       count = sc.parallelize(xrange(1, n+1), slices).map(f).reduce(add)   File
>   "/Users/yuanwang/programming/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/rdd.py",
>   line 759, in reduce
>       vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()   File "/Users/yuanwang/programming/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/rdd.py",
>   line 723, in collect
>       bytesInJava = self._jrdd.collect().iterator()   File "/Users/yuanwang/programming/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 538, in **call**   File
>   "/Users/yuanwang/programming/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o26.collect. : org.apache.spark.SparkException:
>   Job aborted due to stage failure: All masters are unresponsive! Giving
>   up.   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
>     at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)  at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)   at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)  at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

I am pretty sure I am not connect to Spark cluster correctly, has anyone successfully connect spark cluster on cloud engine?

Comment: Can you run simple programs on the Spark shell on your GCE cluster?

Comment: i can load from google cloud storage, and count lines.

Comment: Is Spark running on YARN?

Comment: I am using https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/mc/template/hadoop, it is running on a hadoop cluster

Comment: Not sure how clusters launched like that are configured, so I can't tell if it's a config issue or not. As an alternative, you can try this [Spark-GCE launch script](https://github.com/sigmoidanalytics/spark_gce) and see if you get a workable cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can run jobs from the master:

ssh to the master node:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone <zone> hadoop-m-<hash>
```

and then:

```
$ cd /home/hadoop/spark-install
$ spark-submit examples/src/main/python/pi.py 10
```

and somewhere in the output you should see: something like:

> Pi is roughly 3.140100

It looks like you are trying to do remote submission of jobs.  I'm not sure how you get that to work, but you can submit jobs from on the master.

BTW, as a routine operation, you can validate your spark installation with:

```
cd /usr/local/share/google/bdutil-0.35.2/extensions/spark
sudo chmod 755 spark-validate-setup.sh
./spark-validate-setup.sh
```

Comment: so is there a way to submit job remotely? via http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/cluster-overview.html maybe? I am new to spark